# Change quantity to 3 decimals and update price on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my store, I have fruits product which I want to sell the quantity based on kg and grams (1.000 = 1kg, 0.500 = 0.5kg or 500grams, etc.) currently is on 1,2,3,4. This is my code ( Shopify, Jquery )

```
jQuery(".button").on("click", function() {
    var oldValue = jQuery("#quantity").val(),
        newVal = 1;

    if (jQuery(this).text() == "+") {
      newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
    } else if (oldValue > 1) {
      newVal = parseInt(oldValue) - 1;
    }

    jQuery(".product-single #quantity").val(newVal);
    {% if settings.display_subtotal  %} 
    updatePricing();
    {% endif %}
  });
  
  
  
  {% if settings.display_subtotal %} 
  //update price when changing quantity
  function updatePricing() {
    
    
    //try pattern one before pattern 2
    var regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
    var unitPriceTextMatch = jQuery('.product-single #ProductPrice').text().match(regex);
   
    if (!unitPriceTextMatch) {
      regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
      unitPriceTextMatch = jQuery('.product-single #ProductPrice').text().match(regex);        
    }
   
    if (unitPriceTextMatch) {
      var unitPriceText = unitPriceTextMatch[0];     
      var unitPrice = unitPriceText.replace(/[.|,]/g,'');
      var quantity = parseInt(jQuery('.product-single  #quantity').val());
      var totalPrice = unitPrice * quantity;

      var totalPriceText = Shopify.formatMoney(totalPrice, window.money_format);
      regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;     
      if (!totalPriceText.match(regex)) {
        regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
      } 
      totalPriceText = totalPriceText.match(regex)[0];

      var regInput = new RegExp(unitPriceText, "g"); 
      var totalPriceHtml = jQuery('.product-single #ProductPrice').html().replace(regInput ,totalPriceText);

      jQuery('.product-single .total-price span').html(totalPriceHtml);     
    }
  }

  jQuery('.product-single #quantity').on('change', updatePricing);
  {% endif %}
  
  
  
  var t = false

jQuery('input').focus(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this)
    
    t = setInterval(

    function () {
        if (($this.val() < 1 ) && $this.val().length != 0) {
            if ($this.val() < 1) {
                $this.val(1)
            }

          
            jQuery('.min-qty-alert').fadeIn(1000, function () {
                jQuery(this).fadeOut(500)
            })
        }
    }, 50)
})

jQuery('input').blur(function () {
    if (t != false) {
        window.clearInterval(t)
        t = false;
    }
})
```

So let's say the price is 4$ for kg, for 200g (on quantity field 0.200) so the total price should update whatever is 200g of 4$. I just need this, so anyone who can help me/give me an idea, I'll be grateful

Comment: you can use ```toFixed() ``` for setting the number of decimals. Example: ```Number(10).toFixed(3) ``` will return ```"10.000" ```

Comment: i tried that but it said Jquery......toFixed(3) is not a function